# Chips with autocomplete (no jQuery and 1.0.0-alpha3) does not initialize

Tags: materialize

**Expected Behavior**

Create the Chips component with the autocomplete option using Javascript (no jQuery).

**Current Behavior**

Running the component I get the message

```
materialize.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
at n.value (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-alpha.3/js/materialize.min.js:6:104488)
    at new n (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-alpha.3/js/materialize.min.js:6:101364)
    at Function.value (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-alpha.3/js/materialize.min.js:6:11799)
    at Function.value (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-alpha.3/js/materialize.min.js:6:106244)
```

### Steps to Reproduce

Codepen link: [Using 1.0.0-alpha3](https://codepen.io/marcosdefontes/pen/VyzeNL)

HTML:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 m6">
    Groups:                            
    <div class="chips chips-autocomplete-groups">     </div>
  </div>                       
</div>
```

JS:

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('.chips-autocomplete-groups');
if (elem != null) {
    var insChipAC = M.Chips.init(elem, {
        placeholder: 'Enter a group',
        secondaryPlaceholder: '+Group',
        autocompleteOptions: {
            data: {
                'Alex': null,
                'Brandy': null,
                'Charlie': null
            },
            limit: Infinity,
            minLength: 1
        }        
    });    
}
```

In **1.0.0-alpha2** version I was able to create the component
Codepen link: [Using 1.0.0-alpha2](https://codepen.io/marcosdefontes/pen/XVadob)

### Environment

- Version used: 1.0.0-alpha3
- Browser Name and version: Chrome 63.0.3239.108
- Operating System and version (desktop or mobile): Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug. Fixed in https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/pull/5514 [(link do pull request)](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/pull/5514)